# Are Hennas Tattoos and how do they fit into Hinduism?

Tags: culture

Are Hennas tattoos and how do they fit into the equation?

> Often, they start on the hand and the design goes up and down both arms. It's important to note that henna tattoos aren't really "tattoos." Henna only stains the skin. A henna tattoo will fade in time, about 2-4 weeks, depending on the type of henna that has been used.

Comment: Designs made using henna can be termed as 'temporary' tattoos if you want, there are no restrictions on them in Hinduism, in fact it's part n parcel of many Hindu festivals/occasions !

Comment: I think they are also used in vivaah sanskaar yet more in a tradition as opposed to religion.

Comment: While the question is off topic, it may be valuable to explain why and how it is off topic (rather than simply closing it) for people who search for such information in future.