# Is the popular practice of applying Mehndi (Henna tattoo) during weddings supported by scriptures?

Tags: practice, marriage, culture, festivals

From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehndi)

> Mehndi is a form of body art and temporary skin decoration usually drawn on hands or legs, in which decorative designs are created on a person's body, using a paste, created from the powdered dry leaves of the henna plant (*Lawsonia inermis*).

Applying Mehndi designs during weddings has been a favorite staple for Hindu marriages, especially by the bride and other female relatives. Even the groom and some males apply a bit of Mehndi on their hands in some cases. In fact, this practice nowadays is kind of actually an "essential ritual", if you'll.

This is not just limited to weddings but extends to other auspicious events and festivals too:

> Mehndi in Indian tradition is typically applied during Hindu weddings and festivals like Karva Chauth, Vat Purnima, Diwali, Bhai Dooj, Navraathri, Durga Pooja and Teej.

#### Question -

##### Is the practice of applying Mehendi during weddings and other auspicious days, sourced from, and prescribed by any canonical scriptures? Do we have any mention of Mehendi being used by people in any of our texts?

---

<sup>Slightly related to this question (but not a duplicate):
 [Are Hennas Tattoos and how do they fit into Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36781/are-hennas-tattoos-and-how-do-they-fit-into-hinduism)</sup>